# Enabling tmpfs on an already installed system

Tags: linux, partition, fstab, tmpfs, tmp

Right now a system uses LVM on LUKS, with only 2 lvm partitions `/` and `/home`.

If I now want to make use of `tmpfs` for `/tmp` and `/var/tmp`, can I just
add the necessary changes to `/etc/fstab` and it will work without breaking anything? Or could this cause any problems?

```
tmpfs           /tmp            tmpfs           size=16G,noatime        0 0
tmpfs           /var/tmp        tmpfs           size=1G,noatime         0 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should work - assuming you have enough RAM for that 16GiB ramdisk and all your running applications! If you only have 16GiB RAM total, it doesn't really make sense to allocate so much memory to a ramdisk that it could push running applications - or itself - partially into swap space, because that would slow your system down to a crawl.

You probably don't want to have some existing applications using - or trying to use - temporary files "hidden behind" the mount point though, so I would reboot the system in order to activate this change, rather than just mounting /tmp and /var/tmp on the running system.

Also, if there are a large amount of temporary files already there, you could stop all running services (e.g. by going into single-user mode - but that won't work if you have to connect to the machine over ssh) and then remove the *contents* of /tmp and /var/tmp, before rebooting, to reclaim some disk space and inodes. But do not remove the *directories themselves*, because they are the mount points and must exist.

Answer (score 1):

> Right now **a system** uses LVM...

Then you should follow that system's boot procedure and installation guide/tool. With systemd the rule is:

/tmp should be a tmpfs  (fast, and files do not survive reboot)

/var/tmp should stay on a real device (for big files, needs emptying)

I see that these two dirs are only used by systemd itself on my system right now; much more is going on on

/var/run

which also has a tmpfs mounted. I have no tmpfs line in etc/fstab.

And: some initscript or systemd still has to mount these two points, if possible at the right time, either one by one:

mount /tmp; mount /var/tmp

or by kind of abusing the --all option:

mount -a

According to systemd on my archlinux both LVM and tmp.mount are done independently and early on.

As pointed out in the first answer: make sure the /tmp is more or less empty when you first start to mount it as tmpfs. Otherwise you could have Gigas of old tmp-files hidden for years under your /tmp ramdisk.